# Как с помощью VK API понять что человек пишет после нажатия на кнопку в боте?

Tags: vkontakte-api, бот

Всем привет, столкнулся с проблемой что в VK API отсутсвует четкое описание такого поведения.
Пример поведения: есть три кнопки и только после нажатия кнопки "я хочу написать что-то создателю бота" мне интересно что он ввел.
Если на кнопки можно без проблема навесить Payload, то с сообщением пользователя после нажатия сложнее. Буду рад если кто-то подскажет.

Пишу на го с помощью библиотеки https://github.com/SevereCloud/vksdk, но в случае отсутвия функционала думаю зашарю в проекте и сделаю изменения в зависимости от API

P.S. появилась идея как это захардкодить, но стараюсь себя держать подальше от этой мысли.

Answer (score 0):

Создай что-то типа сессии и заноси туда статус нажатия кнопки, если после нажатия пользователь не написал текст а нажал другую кнопку к примеру, обнуляй сессию. Так же можно сделать параметр time и заносить время нажатия кнопки. И если прошло более 5 мин к примеру, так же обнулять сессию.

Comment: написал по патерну state